# How do I remove extra parsing characters in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have the following lists of lists:

```
animals = [('dog', 'cat'), ('mouse', 'bird')]
```

I would like to reduce it to:

```
animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bird']
```

is there a simpler way to have the result above than doing something like this:

```
animals = [('dog', 'cat'), ('mouse', 'bird')]

final = []
for a in animals:
    final.append(a[0])
    final.append(a[1])
print final
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(animals))
['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bird']
```

Or a nested `list comprehension`:

```
>>> [anim for item in animals for anim in item]
['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'bird']
```

For tiny list use the list comprehension version, otherwise use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`.

```
>>> animals = [('dog', 'cat'), ('mouse', 'bird')]
>>> %timeit list(chain.from_iterable(animals))
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.31 us per loop
>>> %timeit [anim for item in animals for anim in item]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.13 us per loop

>>> animals = [('dog', 'cat'), ('mouse', 'bird')]*100
>>> %timeit list(chain.from_iterable(animals))
10000 loops, best of 3: 31.5 us per loop
>>> %timeit [anim for item in animals for anim in item]
10000 loops, best of 3: 73.7 us per loop

>>> animals = [('dog', 'cat'), ('mouse', 'bird')]*1000
>>> %timeit list(chain.from_iterable(animals))
1000 loops, best of 3: 296 us per loop
>>> %timeit [anim for item in animals for anim in item]
1000 loops, best of 3: 733 us per loop
```